# Unable to Build Core-plot with Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot, xcode6.4

Please check the attached image
[image]

I have no clue what this error means.

NOTE: I have added core-plot into my project using cocoa-pods.

Comment: what error did u get ?

Comment: The build fails at these typedef locations:

 typedef NSArray<NSNumber *> *CPTNumberArray; saying "Expected ';' after top level declarator "

Comment: pls check the image which i have attached in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Plot 2.0 requires Xcode 7. It uses the new Objective-C generic collection notation. It will run on iOS 6, but requires the latest Xcode to build.